# Render problems with layout visualization inside Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library, android-styles

I'm developing an Android app for 18-28 SDK. Version of support libraries: 28.0.0-alpha1.  I've began to make my project and met the follow issues with visualization of layouts in Android studio:
1) Action bar is not displayed. Error messages:

```
Render problem: Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error.

The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContextView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.v7.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show 
sample data when shown in the IDE.  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception 
Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener Copy stack to clipboard
```

2) BottomNavigationView is not displayed. Error messages:

```
Render problem: Failed to find style 'bottomNavigationStyle' in current theme

Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme 
combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme 
style references.
```

I've been tried to google decisions and already made these steps, which didn't help me:
1)With ActionBar i added Base prefix to the current app theme root in the styles.xml like that:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

It helped me to remove above error message but I still can't see my default toolbar. Another thing I tried is to downgrade support library till 28.0.0-alpha1 version (previously it was the latest 28.0.0-rc2) 2) For bottom navigation I've tried to add style attribute accordingly to the: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView.Colored"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Hope you will show me decision accurate to my situation